Computer randomly goes to sleep
My computer (running Kubuntu) randomly goes to sleep. Some days nothing happens, sometimes it sleeps in the morning, sometimes it sleeps towards the end of the day. There doesn't seem to be a pattern. There is no logout screen displayed before going to sleep, but after logging back on, I see it with a countdown.
I tracked this down in the syslog the last time it happened:
2024-09-30T09:31:34.068852-07:00 kubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
2024-09-30T09:31:34.070917-07:00 kubuntu-desktop anacron[98399]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2024-09-30
2024-09-30T09:31:34.071696-07:00 kubuntu-desktop anacron[98399]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
2024-09-30T09:31:34.073108-07:00 kubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-30T09:31:45.532565-07:00 kubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[3641]: [session uid=1000 pid=3641] Activating service name='org.kde.LogoutPrompt' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=3899 comm="/usr/bin/ksmserver" label="unconfined")
2024-09-30T09:31:45.751223-07:00 kubuntu-desktop kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
2024-09-30T09:31:45.752662-07:00 kubuntu-desktop ModemManager[2517]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
2024-09-30T09:31:45.752832-07:00 kubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2441]: <info>  [1727713905.7523] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
2024-09-30T09:31:45.752882-07:00 kubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2441]: <info>  [1727713905.7524] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-30T09:31:45.754339-07:00 kubuntu-desktop plasmashell[6458]: [6452:6480:0930/093145.754106:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(483)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
2024-09-30T09:31:45.771080-07:00 kubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2441]: <info>  [1727713905.7710] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-30T09:31:45.771134-07:00 kubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2441]: <info>  [1727713905.7711] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
2024-09-30T09:31:45.771154-07:00 kubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2441]: <info>  [1727713905.7711] device (enp6s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

To me, it looks like something is requesting that my computer go to sleep. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this issue, and searching the internet hasn't helped much (probably because I don't know what I'm looking for).
Output of lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble


don't use Kubuntu personally but in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS the setting is found in Settings -> Power -> Power Saving -> Automatic Suspend which should be set to Off

There is a similar setting in Kubuntu: Power Management -> Activity Power Settings -> Define a special behavior, which I have set to Never shut down the computer or let it go to sleep.
